# Win32 application write output to console using printf

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have an exe developed using win32 application. When I run (double click) the exe GUI should appear and when i call exe from command prompt output should appear in command console.

My issue is how can i redirect output to command window using `printf`? I am able to print in command window using `AllocConsole()`, but new command window is created and output is redirected to new window. I want to print output in same command window where exe is called using Win32 application. Any help appreciated.

Comment: [AttachConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681952.aspx).

Comment: Are you asking how to act like a command line program when run from a command prompt, and run with a GUI when double clicked?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but very closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171017/win32-console-application-that-can-open-windows/29687965#29687965

Comment: There's no good way to do this.  Build two executables, one GUI and one for the command line.

Answer (score 5):

To build on what [wilx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341065/wilx) said (sorry I don't have enough reputation to just comment on his answer) you can use [AttachConsole(...);](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681952(v=vs.85).aspx) So to attach to a console if an only if there is already one available you could use something like:

```
bool bAttachToConsole()
{
    if (!AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS))
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) //already has a console
        {
            if (!AttachConsole(GetCurrentProcessId()))
            {
                DWORD dwLastError = GetLastError();
                if (dwLastError != ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) //already has a console
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Then in your WinMain you can do this:

```
if (bAttachToConsole())
{
    //do your io with STDIN/STDOUT
    // ....
}
else
{
    //Create your window and do IO via your window
    // ....
}
```

Additionally you will have to "fix" the c standard IO handles to use your new console see the following [write up](http://dslweb.nwnexus.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm) for a great example of how to do this.

Comment: The problem is that the command line interface won't know to wait for your program to exit, so your output will be mixed in with the command-line prompt.  The problem is even worse if you need input.

Comment: Good point Harry. Starting from a console app and hiding the console via a argument maybe the only way to get the close with one exe.

Answer (score 1):

This almost does what you want:

```
// Win32Project1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>  // printf, _dup2
#include <io.h>     // _open_osfhandle

void SetupConsole()
{
    AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
    HANDLE hConIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    int fd0 = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)hConIn, 0);
    _dup2(fd0, 0);
    HANDLE hConOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    int fd1 = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)hConOut, 0);
    _dup2(fd1, 1);
    HANDLE hConErr = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    int fd2 = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)hConErr, 0);
    _dup2(fd2, 2);
}

WNDPROC g_pOldProc;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_CLOSE)
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return CallWindowProc(g_pOldProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void GUI(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
                        _T("EDIT"),
                        _T("GUI"),
                        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE,
                        100, 100, 200,200,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        hInstance,
                        NULL
                        );
    g_pOldProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&WindowProc);

    SetWindowText(hWnd, _T("Hello world."));

    MSG m;
    while (GetMessage(&m, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        DispatchMessage(&m);
    }

    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
}

void Console()
{
    SetupConsole();
    printf("Hello world.");
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                       HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                       LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                       int       nCmdShow)
{
    HANDLE hConOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (!hConOut)
        GUI(hInstance);
    else
        Console();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked all submitted solutions here and they didn't work for me.
You can always create (or change to) a CONSOLE [subsystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=msvc-170). However, if you want to enable writing to the Console from a WIN32 appliation, not classidfied as a CONSOLE application, this code will work. After calling this function, you can just use printf (or wprintf).

My code uses [AllocConsole()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole) and then [AttachConsole()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole), pssing to it the current process ID (obtained by calling [GetProcessID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocessid)).

```
void enableConsole()
{
    AllocConsole();
    AttachConsole(GetCurrentProcessId());
    HWND Handle = GetConsoleWindow();
    freopen("CON", "w", stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681952(v=vs.85).aspx) (or use PID) to attach to the existing console.

---

While I have posted my answer already, TBH, I am not sure I do understand your problem exactly. I have some code that has a comment that says (above `AllocConsole()`:

> We ignore the return value here. If we already have a console, it will fail.

Are you sure that you cannot just use `AllocConsole()` unconditionally like I do?

Comment: AllocConsole is only useful if you want to create a new console.  The OP wants to use the existing console (if there is one) or to not have a console at all (if there isn't).

Comment: I tried using AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS), it wil open new cmd window. My problem statement is i open a cmd window and go to location where my exe is present (C:\test.exe) then run exe from same cmd window. On including AttachConsole() output is displayed in new cmd window.

Comment: @user1881297: well, that shouldn't happen.  AttachConsole() isn't supposed to create a new console!  Can you give us [an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Win32Project1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>  // printf
#include <io.h>     // _open_osfhandle, _dup2

void SetupConsole()
{
    BOOL bCreated = AllocConsole();
    if (!bCreated)
        return; // We already have a console.

    HANDLE hConOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    int fd = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)hConOut, 0);
    _dup2(fd, 1);

}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    SetupConsole();
    printf("Hello world!");
    Sleep(10000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: AllocConsole is only useful if you want to create a new console. The OP wants to use the existing console (if there is one) or to not have a console at all (if there isn't).

Comment: I tried using AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS), it wil open new cmd window. My problem statement is i open a cmd window and go to location where my exe is present (C:\test.exe) then run exe from same cmd window. On including AttachConsole() output is displayed in new cmd window.